# How do you expect a mailer function to be called with .deliver in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a test on a service `EmailTrainersAboutMissingReports.call` that expects it to call `TrainerMonitorMailer.missing_run_reports`:

```
describe EmailTrainersAboutMissingReports do

  describe ('::call') do

    context 'missing two group runs' do

      let!(:group_run)    { FactoryGirl.create :group_run, started_at: 1.day.ago }
      let!(:group_run_2)  { FactoryGirl.create :group_run, started_at: 1.day.ago }

      it 'is successful' do
        expect(TrainerMonitorMailer).to receive(:missing_run_reports).with(area,
                                                [group_run, group_run_2])
        EmailTrainersAboutMissingReports.call
      end

    end

  end

end
```

The code for the accompanying service looks like this:

```
class EmailTrainersAboutMissingReports

  def self.call
    response = RunReportMonitor.check_all_got_published_on_time(area)
    unless response.success?
      TrainerMonitorMailer.missing_run_reports(area, response.group_runs_missing_reports).deliver
    end
  end

end
```

Where I'm running into trouble is that I chain the `deliver` method onto the mailer. So when I run the test I receive:

```
undefined method `deliver' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I define the expectation such that it expects missing_run_reports with the parameters above, but also expects this chained to call .deliver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stub the message delivery as well. Return that in your initial expectation and then expect it to receive `deliver`. Like so:

```
it 'is successful' do
  message_delivery = instance_double(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)
  expect(TrainerMonitorMailer).to receive(:missing_run_reports).
                                  with(area, [group_run, group_run_2]).
                                  and_return(message_delivery)
  expect(message_delivery).to receive(:deliver)
  EmailTrainersAboutMissingReports.call
end
```